# Xcode falsely states "Cloud.h" doesn't exist

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, cloud

I'm creating an app that uses [CloudApp](https://github.com/cloudapp/objective-c). I am using "TestHarness" in order to see what to expect when I import it into my app. The problem is, Xcode is continuously saying "'Cloud.h' file not found", when, in fact, it is in the directory. To see what I'm talking about, click [here](http://cl.ly/0p3x2g3A0W3Y1A070Y0T).

I've tried to find anything similar to my question and have either found nothing or it may or may not even be remotely close to what I'm asking for and it was for a lower version of Xcode (I'm using Xcode 4.2, as you can see in the picture).

I'll appreciate any help that I can get. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
#import "Cloud/Cloud.h"
```

Comment: I tried that, but it's still not working. It's still says "'Cloud.h' file not found.

Comment: Did you build the project? I see libCloud.a in red, which means it doesn't exist.

Comment: Also, try it with quotes instead of carrots.

Comment: I clicked on "Build" several times, I've even cleaned it then built it too. But, it still working. As for the "libCloud.a" thing, I'm aware of that, but I'm not too sure how I would be able to get that to work either.

Comment: Did you first try to use the static library and then switch to using the subproject?

Comment: I believe not. How would I do that? Just to let you know, I'm a beginner when it comes to Xcode, so if I don't know something, please understand.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've ben working so hard on it that I didn't check this website for any updates. I've been trying to do all of the solutions, but it's doesn't look like it's working at all. But I did fix it as of right now, although I had to use https://github.com/tmdvs/ios , which had very similar code. But, the point is that it actually works now. Thank you for helping me. I really do appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the path to the CloudApp header file in the application:

- select the target,
- go to 'Build Settings',
- 'Header Search Paths'

(might need to check 'Recursive path').

Comment: :( may be the path to the project isn't right. To be sure the path is ok, start from your project .xcodeproj and look for the hierarchy to reach the cloud app .xcodeproj.